# Extending an extension (SCP) in Magento causes JS errors?

Tags: javascript, magento

I don't think this is an actual JS error, but the symptoms are JS related. I have a Magento 1.7.0.2 installation with SCP (Simple Configurable Products) which works 100% as I want/expect. In my early development I added some methods to 1 specific file in the SCP module, `app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php`.

With these methods inside of the SCP module everything works, however I realise now I really should have created an additional module in the local code pool that extends SCP and put my additional methods in there. So I created Bendart_Matrix. I cut the 3 methods out of SCP's `Configurable.php` and placed them in my own module, `app/code/local/Bendart/Matrix/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php`. Whilst the page still loads, there appear to be some JS errors which ultimately relate to the `Product` JS Object not being created correctly. It doesn't get created with the `.Options` method like it does when my methods are part of SCP.

I can't find a logical reason as to why this is, so I've created some gists of my module (Configurable.php, config.xml and Bendart_Matrix.xml) and the same files from SCP. Once again, if I disable or remove my module and switch the methods back to SCP files, it works. Weird?

SCP config.xml: https://gist.github.com/4327015

SCP Module Declaration XML: https://gist.github.com/4327012

SCP Configurable.php (minus the methods from my file: https://gist.github.com/4326996

My config.xml: https://gist.github.com/4326988

My Module Declaration XML: https://gist.github.com/4326986

My Configurable.php (just the methods in question): https://gist.github.com/4326909

Any help or advice is appreciated as I want to do it properly and remove my methods from the SCP module but there appears to be some dependencies I've missed or something?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you posted, I think the most likely issue is going to be that you have made a change in your layout update that removes a template that is required. You seem to be extending the module correctly and a JS error in generally related to templates in this situation.

*P.S. Slight heads up, came to our attention this morning that SCP doesn't function correctly if somebody adds a configurable product to their basket from the Wishlist page (it adds both the configurable and the simple, this may not matter to you, but with our customised exports and adminhtml updates this caused issues). If you have Wishlist enabled you should bare this in mind.*

Comment: Cags, it's only when I "enable" my module as I said. But you can see in my module's config that layouts aren't even mentioned or addressed.  When I say a "JS Error" what actually happens is the configurable product page loads with an "As low as £0.00" price and any manipulations of the drop-downs result in an opConfig is not defined. If I disable my module and revert to just SCP with my methods inside, it works fine.

Comment: You module's config file includes a layout update node (`/frontend/layouts/updates/matrix/file`), how is this not mentioning or addressing layouts?

Comment: Sorry didn't see that, so would my matrix.xml "overwrite" the SCP file meaning everything in the SCP is invalid? It's unlikely as the simpleconfigurableproducts.xml file contains template files and 1 js file, all of the template files work and the js file IS included with my module enabled.

Comment: Your matrix.xml file won't overwrite the simpleconfigurableproducts.xml file per se, both will be parsed. From what I remember of SCP it has several different inline js blocks that are required for a page to function correctly. So if you are changing the type of any blocks on the page, or the template it is using that is likely the cause of your issues. Another issue I remember having was with out of stock products, because different templates are loaded based on this, the information isn't always there. This could be down to our overloaded templates though.

Comment: I've narrowed my 0.00 price down to in the view.phtml there is this line: `<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>`. When my module is enabled, the response from JsonConfig shows the `productPrice` as 0. I can test this in JS console by doing `optionsPrice` and looking at the contents of the object. Not sure why this is? Again it's only when my module is enabled

Comment: Try checking out `OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Block_Product_Price` which I think will output the initial value on page load.

Comment: Ok, I've taken a look at that file and I think I see what you mean. I've popped some debugs and echo's in there and nothing shows, so I'm guessing that file isn't even being called. However, I do remember reading somewhere about issues with `parent::` calls, of which this `Price.php` has one. Is this something you're aware of? Here's `Price.php` https://gist.github.com/4328523

Comment: Also I've copied `Price.php` to my own module in `Catalog/Blocks/Product/` and nothing. Oddly I can't even get it to break by putting typo's in etc?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've fixed one issue thanks to @Cags.

I noticed whilst turning template hints on that scpoptions.phtml wasn't being included in comparison to my live working version. I added the following lines (taken from `simpleconfigurableproducts.xml`)

```
    <reference name="product.info.options">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/scpoptions.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

This fixed all the JS warnings about Product.Options and any other warnings I had. It also ensured that the product price was updated correctly once I started selecting custom options etc.

Now, one last issue, when I load the product page, before I select ANYTHING, the price shows as 0.00. As soon as I select a drop-down the price "kicks in" and it works from there on in, it just appears to be the initial page load. I've compared template files with my live site that works (but doesn't have my module) so again it's something to do with the inclusion of my module, but what?

Cheers.